# Almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

Let $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be finite measure space and $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of finite real measurable functions so that $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. We say $f_n\rightarrow f$ **almost uniformly** if $\epsilon>0$, there is $E\subseteq A$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E^c$ and $\mu(E)<\epsilon$.

**I want to show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly implies convergence in $\mu$**. For this, suppose not. Then 
$$\exists \eta,\epsilon>0:\forall N\in \mathbb{N}:\exists n>N:\mu(\mid f_n-f\mid\geq\epsilon)\geq \eta, $$
 i.e., for infinitely many points $n\in \mathbb{N}$. From the definition of almost uniform convergence, $\exists E:\mu(E)<\eta$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E^c$. Contradiction.

**Question**

It seems intuitive to me. But how to deduce this contradiction precisely?
I know that if $x\in E$, then it must satify the negation of uniform convergence which is 
$$\exists \epsilon>0:\forall N\in \mathbb{N}:\exists n>N:\mid f_n-f\mid\geq\epsilon.$$
Now, $x$ may not be in $\{f_n \text{ does not converge in measure to } f \}$ if $\mu(\mid f_n(x)-f(x)\mid\geq\epsilon)<\eta$. So I conclude that $$\{f_n \text{ does not converge in measure to } f \}\subseteq E$$ implying that $\eta>\mu(E)\geq \eta$; a contradiction.

My argument seems right but also very inefficient. How could you express this idea as clean as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way without going for contradiction: Let $\epsilon >0$ be fixed and consider some $\delta >0$.

By almost uniform convergence, there exists some $E$ with $\mu(E)\leq \delta$ and some $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies \forall x\in E^c, |f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon$.

For $n\geq N$, note the inclusion $(|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon) \subset E$, hence $\mu((|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon))\leq \mu(E)\leq \delta$.

Hence $\forall \delta>0, \exists N, n\geq N \implies \mu((|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon))\leq \delta$. Thus $ \mu((|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon)) \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! The inclusion $\{\mid f_n-f\mid\geq \epsilon\}\subset E$ that I don't understand.  What is this infinity-norm that you wrote?

Comment: @Danmat I removed the infinity norm (which denotes the sup-norm), do you understand now ?

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence? And then the complement of the latter is contained in the complement of the former.

Comment: @Danmat I just wrote the definition of uniform convergence on $E^c$. Pointwise convergence is not used in the proof.

Comment: But, $E$ is constituted of elements in $A$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ does not converge uniformly, right?

Comment: @Danmat $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E^c$, and you have no information a priori about what happens on $E$. But you don't need to care since $E$ has small measure.

Comment: From the uniform convergence, how to conclude that you have the inclusion? Sorry, I really don't understand that.

Comment: @Danmat You know that $(n\geq N \text{ and } x\in E^c) \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon$. So if you have some $n\geq N$ and $x$ such that $ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon$, then necessarily $x\in E$. Hence the inclusion $(|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon) \subset E$.

Comment: Oh, I thought that there could be some uniformly convergent sequences on $E$, as you mentioned that there is no prior information about $E$.

Answer (score 4):

This is proved more succinctly by a direct proof.

Given $\varepsilon > 0,$ let $E$ be as in the definition of almost-uniform convergence.  Then there is some $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies
$$\mu(E^c \cap \{|f_n-f|\geq\varepsilon\}) = 0$$
What does this imply for $\mu(|f_n-f|\geq \varepsilon)?$

Comment: How to conclude that $\{\mid f_n-f\mid \}\subseteq E$?

Comment: @Danmat Forget about $E$ for a second.  On $E^c,$ the functions converge uniformly.  This means that there will be some $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n - f| < \varepsilon.$  In particular, on $E^c,$ $$n \geq N \implies \{|f_n - f| \geq \varepsilon\} = \emptyset.$$  This directly means $$E^c \cap \{|f_n - f| \geq \varepsilon\} = \emptyset.$$  If you want, then you can use the property of sets that $$A^c \cap B = \emptyset \iff B \subseteq A$$

Comment: Very nice! Now, it's all clear to me!